# How to nest lein projects?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have a lein project called foo. Foo has a resources directory in which I have another lein project called bar, with its own project.clj.

foo's project.clj:

```
(defproject foo "0.1.0"
  :description "Instaboi's drone autonomy software"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
                 [nrepl "0.8.0"]
                 ]
  :repl-options {:init-ns foo.core}
  :plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.25.3"]
            [lein-environ "1.2.0"]]
  :source-paths ["src" "resources/bar/src"]
)
```

Notice that I add a source path "resources/bar/src", so that I can use bar's namespaces in foo.

bar's project.clj:

```
(defproject bar "1.47-SNAPSHOT"

  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url  "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[criterium "0.4.5"]]}}
  :java-source-paths ["java"]
  :plugins [[lein-tools-deps "0.4.5"]]
  :middleware [lein-tools-deps.plugin/resolve-dependencies-with-deps-edn]
  :lein-tools-deps/config {:config-files [:install :user :project]})
```

Notice that bar uses a middleware to `resolve-dependencies-with-deps-edn`, and so there's a deps.edn in bar's root folder:

```
{
 :paths ["src"]

 :deps {
        org.clojure/clojure      {:mvn/version "1.10.1"}
        camel-snake-kebab        {:mvn/version "0.4.0"}
        org.clojure/data.json    {:mvn/version "1.0.0"}
        }
 }
```

The problem is that these dependencies are not loaded, because they aren't present in foo's dependencies. This causes an error when bar's modules are used in foo. How to make sure that the bar project is also loaded when a repl is run or a jar is created in foo's root?

Answer (score 0):

I would build/install bar separately. I believe you can use [lein profiles](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md) to achieve this from within Foo's project.clj. This way you can later add it as a dependency in Foo.

I'm suggesting this since you seem to only need access to bar's namespaces inside Foo and there's no clear reason to have them coupled.